# how to print a result data in same the line in bash command?

Tags: bash

I have my command below and I want to have the result in the same line with delimeters. My command:

```
Array=("GET" "POST" "OPTIONS" "HEAD")

echo $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
for i in "${Array[@]}"
do
    cat /home/log/myfile_log | grep "$(date "+%d/%b/%Y:%H")"| awk -v last5=$(date --date="-5 min" "+%M") -F':' '$3>=last5 && $3<last5+5{print}' | egrep -a "$i" | wc -l
done
```

Results is:

```
2019-01-01 13:27
1651
5760
0
0
```

I want to have the result below:

```
2019-01-01 13:27,1651,5760,0,0
```

Comment: @F.Eliasius : Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). As it stands now, it is nearly unreadable.

Comment: Array=("GET" "POST" "OPTIONS" "HEAD")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks (to me) like the overall objective is to scan `/home/log/myfile.log` for entries that have occurred within the last 5 minutes **and** which match one of the 4 entries in `${Array[@]}`, keeping count of the matches along the way and finally printing the current date and the counts to a single line of output.

I've opted for a complete rewrite that uses `awk`'s abilities of pattern matching, keeping counts and generating a single line of output:

```
date1=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")      # current date
date5=$(date --date="-5 min" "+%M")  # date from 5 minutes ago

awk -v d1="${date1}" -v d5="${date5}" -F":" '
BEGIN      { keep=0                  # init some variables
             g=0
             p=0
             o=0
             h=0
           }

$3>=d5 && $3<d5+5 { keep=1 }         # do we keep processing this line?

!keep      { next }                  # if not then skip to next line

/GET/      { g++  }                  # increment our counters
/POST/     { p++  }
/OPTIONS/  { o++  }
/HEAD/     { h++  }
           { keep=0 }                # reset keep flag for next line

                                     # print results to single line of output
END        { printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", d1, g, p, o, h }
' <(grep "$(date '+%d/%b/%Y:%H')" /home/log/myfile_log)
```

**NOTE**: The OP may need to revisit the `<(grep "$(date ...)" /home/log/myfile.log)` to handle timestamp periods that span hours, days, months and years, eg, `14:59 - 16:04`, `12/31/2019 23:59 - 01/01/2020 00:04`, etc.

Yeah, it's a bit verbose but a bit easier to understand; OP can rewrite/reduce as sees fit.

Comment: my array are strings to calculate the number of those strings every 5mn,   Array=("GET" "POST" "OPTIONS" "HEAD"), also ur solution dont meat my requirement because i need to have space between date and time  2020-06-10 08:09, my file log is like thais: 10.1.1.1 - - [01/Jan/2020:03:50:02 +0100] "POST /home.php HTTP/1.1" 206 3807 "-" "hpo/3.0544.5.2 Series60/2.8 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1" "213
123456789" **0/1909**

Comment: if your array's values can change over time then you'll need to include that bit of info in your question; on the other hand if the array contents will always be the same then the proposed `awk` solution handles that (ie, hardcoded array values == hardcoded `awk` patterns); not sure what you mean by space between date and time ... `date1` does have a space between date and time (just like in the question) ...

Comment: i did the below script and its working as i expect, thanks all for your support:

Comment: Array=("GET" "POST" "OPTIONS" "HEAD")
output_test=$(printf "%(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M,)T" $(date +%s);for i in "${Array[@]}"; do cat /home/log/myfile_log |grep "$(date "+%d/%b/%Y:%H")"|awk -v last5=$(date --date="-5 min" "+%M") -F':' '$3>=last5 && $3<last5+5{print}'|egrep -a "$i"|wc -l| tr "\n" ","; done)
echo $output_test >> /home/log/last_output.txt